# jdbcrealm.invaliduserreason Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception

Tags: java, security, authentication, glassfish-4

I tried this tutorial http://java.dzone.com/articles/jdbc-realm-and-form-based with GlassFish 4 and getting the error:

> SEVERE:   jdbcrealm.invaliduserreason
>   WARNING:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception

I tried many diffrent things such as setting the log level to Finest,took the case sensitivity on table/columnnames into consideration, added "none" in the Algorithm statment (  [SEVERE: jdbcrealm.invaliduserreason WEB9102: Web Login Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11007071/severe-jdbcrealm-invaliduserreason-web9102-web-login-failed) ), tried diffrent password hashes ( [LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941713/loginexception-login-failed-security-exception)), setSHA-256 in Password Encryption Algorithm and in Digest Alogirthm but none of suggested solutions worked for me.

I think the problem is connected to the "Password Encryption Algorithm:" statement, because this "Password Encryption Algorithm:" doesn't exist in the tutorial (he is using Glassfish 3.x)

This is my current Glassfish configuration.
[image]

Has someone an idea what I can try else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after setting the charset to UTF-8 it seems to be working. Also I can recommend video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xsU6juUZd0 which is using glassfish 4.